why npm version doesn't work on terminal?
C:\Users\raffi> node -v
v20.16.0

C:\Users\raffi>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js"' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

I wanted to check the npm version for my react project on my terminal but it is excecuting me a message error.

Possibly helpful

you first have to make sure that npm is installed in correct directory. It is usually installed with nodejs in same directory
cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
dir

if npm is there then i think you need to add its path to PATH environment variable
Search for env in the search and you will see the option to set the environment variables. Then click on it and then click on System variables and find Path variable and select it. Click Edit . Add the path to both npm and nodejs. In my case the path was like this
C:\Program Files\nodejs\


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\

after that click ok to clsoe all dialog boxes and restart your powershell or cmd to take changes
and then try checking npm -v

hello my freind, I did it the same thing but nothing new, it still showing me the same error message.

If it help try reinstalling node or some other version of it.
Make sure the PATH is correctly set to the C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\ ("The path can varry soo double check ")

Locate the Node.js Installation Directory
Update the PATH Environment Variable
Restart Your Computer
Reinstall Node.js

hello my freind thank you so much, , I did the exact thing and it still doesn't work any other solution ?
